# What are the distributions of these Gaussian variables?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, covariance, means

I'm just wondering if I have the correct answers to these questions.

Let $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ be multivariate Gaussian distributed with mean vector and covariance matrix:
$$
\mu = (0,1,2)^T, \quad \Sigma = ((4,5,1),(5,9,-2),(1,-2,1))
$$
What is the distribution of $(Z,X)^T$?

I have
$$
(Z,X)^T \sim ( (2,0)^T, ((1,1),(1,4)) )
$$
Calculate the distribution of $(Z,X)^T | Y = 4$.

I have
$$
(Z,X)^T | Y = 4 \sim ( (11/3,-2/3)^T, ((-16/9,19/9),(19/9,32/9)) )
$$
What is the distribution of $2X - 3Y$?
I have
$$
2X-3Y \sim (-3, -65)
$$

Comment: Do you mean that $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are real valued Gaussian random variables and that $(X,Y,Z)^T$ is multivariate Gaussian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The first one is correct.
- The second one follow this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions). But you can tell it is net correct as the diagonal elements of the covariance matrix can NOT be negative.
- The last one follows:
  $$
  aX + bY \sim N(a\mu_X + b\mu_Y, a^2\sigma_X^2 + b^2\sigma_Y^2 + 2ab\sigma_{X,Y})
  $$
  so, it is not correct. BTW, variance can NOT be negative.